# Loop is not working correctly

Tags: c, loops, infinite

I'm trying to make my loop take a user input, and if the value is 1 through 9, the loop finishes (this part is working properly). But if the user input is not a number 1 - 9, then the program should display an error message, then ask for user input once more, and re-check if the input is a number 1 - 9. When testing this, if I input the letter 'g', then the program spits out the error message indefinitely, rather than just once. Why is this?

Here's the code:

```
int playerMove;

printf("Please enter a number 1 - 9:\n");

  for(;;)
  {
   scanf("%d", &playerMove);

    if(playerMove > 0 && playerMove < 10)
    {
      printf("\nYou have selected position %d. \n\n", playerMove);
      break;
    }

    else 
    {
      printf("Invalid selection. Please enter a number 1 - 9:\n");
    }
  }
```

Comment: How do you know your call to `scanf()` actually worked?  You're ignoring the return value.

Comment: What would you assume happens when `scanf` is expecting an integer input (`%d`) and you give it a non-integer value?

Comment: @rdowell I assumed it would take the decimal value of the ascii character, in this case 'g', which is 103, and use that value. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @JulianBraha If that were the case, then '1' would be read as 49, which is the ascii code for that character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `scanf` encounters characters that don't match the given format specifier, those characters are left in the input buffer.  The `%d` format specifier expects decimal digits, so it stops reading once a non-digit is read.

By entering "g", the `scanf` call reads nothing and the "g" is left in the buffer.  The same happens on subsequent iterations, resulting in an infinite loop.

Use `fgets` instead to read a line of text, then use `sscanf` to attempt to read a number from that line.  If it returns 1 the conversion was successful.  If it returns 0, non-numeric input was read and you read another line:

```
for(;;) {
    char line[100];
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    int result = sscanf(line, "%d", &playerMove);

    if (result == 1 && playerMove > 0 && playerMove < 10)
        printf("\nYou have selected position %d. \n\n", playerMove);
        break;
    } else {
        printf("Invalid selection. Please enter a number 1 - 9:\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not trust user input, you should read input as a string (with gets for example) and then parse this string.